# Cleaning shapes of polygon layer with overlaps and gaps using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a layer of polygons where the shapes are quite messy with gaps and overlaps, see example:

[image: gaps and overlaps]

It's clear that the polygons are supposed to be contiguous and are supposed to roughly follow the streets.

Does anyone know of a pre-made tool, package, script, etc, or programmatic strategy, that would allow me to clean a dataset like this?

I've heard of the [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm) tool

However this does not completely fix this problem since it modifies nodes of the shape all along it's boundary (not just along the sides where there are gaps/overlaps).

Comment: Integrate **is** the pre-made tool. If you want intelligence applied to the process, a tool is precluded, and you need to fall back on topology creation and editing.

Comment: Try Eliminate in data management toolbox

Answer (score 2):

Here's several options you might explore.  (You might try different tolerance settings on the Integrate tool (use a copy or an edit session since it operates on your layer directly) but the problem often is that a setting big enough to catch the gaps and overlaps does change the layer elsewhere.)

1. You can roughly replicate the coverage style clean by using the Feature to Line and Point (inside poly option) tools, then using the Feature to Polygon tool with the points providing the attributes.  You need to set a tolerance but you can keep it small enough not to change shapes generally.  Then you can use the Eliminate tool to automate getting rid of the filled in gaps (select for polys with no attributes) and getting rid of overlaps (select for polys under a certain size, it's not perfect).  This doesn't align polys to your streets.
2. You could look at the Snap Geoprocessing Tool.  I haven't used it (ET Geowizards has a tool I've used) but look at its help.  You would use it to snap your polys to the streets edge.  You  may need to play around with the distance settings.  You don't have to do the whole layer at once, you can go around in sections, and select just the polys you want to apply the tool to at any time.
3. You could use the align to shape tool on the Advanced Editing toolbar.  This is manual but you can cover a lot of ground depending on the layers.  Start editing your polys, start the tool, select a tolerance buffer big enough to catch most of your gaps and overlaps, turn off your polys, then run the tool across your streets layer for as long as you like, turn your polys back on and make sure the tool has them and not the streets selected, then hit align.  Check your results, you may need to play a bit with the buffer.  If good save your results and repeat.  This does align your polys to the streets.